# Is there rule exist that son of Skywalker must not become a Jedi?

Tags: star-wars, the-empire-strikes-back

Emperor says to Darth Vader:

> Emperor: **The son of Skywalker must not become a Jedi.**

Is there rule exist that son of Skywalker must not become a Jedi?

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It’s only a rule in the sense that it is a command from Palpatine.  He is simply acknowledging that he sees the son of Anakin Skywalker becoming a Jedi as a threat to him.